# jquery UI dialog on link click - open file

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this working on my production site, but I'm working on a new site version and cannot get this to open the link in a modal dialog.  The page has this code on it:

```
<a class="dialogify" id="TosLink" href="http://link.to.my.site.com/common/legal/termsAndConditions.htm" title="Terms and Conditions">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

I'm including jquery and jquery-ui on the page and then using this to configure the click:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 450,
        buttons: {
            "Dismiss": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $(".ui-dialog-title").css({
        "font-size": +16 + "px"
    });
    $(".dialogify").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog").html("");
        $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Loading...").dialog("open");
        $("#dialog").load(this.href, function () {
            $(this).dialog("option", "title", $(this).find("h1").text());
            $(this).find("h1").remove();
        });
    });
});
```

I put an alert(this.href) just above the .load and it's getting the correct URL but nothing happens.  No error is shown in the console or firebug.

EDIT - bad copy paste - had extra function() { - removed from code but still won't open the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have

> $(function () {

repeated in the second line?
It's unnecessary.

I believe the reason for your code not working is because second parameter of .load() should be data and the callback function is the 3rd argument. I had the SAME problem. I fixed it by using an empty array (array(), {}, or simply null) in lieu of data.

Change your code to:

```
$("#dialog").load(this.href, null, function () {
            $(this).dialog("option", "title", $(this).find("h1").text());
            $(this).find("h1").remove();
        });
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: bad copy paste - I edited and removed the extra function(){ } but it's still not working

Comment: jQuery has both an event handler, load() and method load() by same name. The difference is, http://api.jquery.com/load/ one of them treats THIRD argument as a callback function while http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ treats SECOND argument as an event HANDLER

Comment: And that seems to have solved it!  Thank you so much - I've been banging my head on this for a while.  Not sure why it works on the old site without the null but working fine now.